# Who is passing false inside Unslider.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am debugging a plugin called Unslider.js, and I have hit a small difficulty. Inside Unslider.js there is a object literal that looks like this:

```
_this.o = {
            speed: 500,     // animation speed, false for no transition (integer or boolean)
            delay: 3000,    // delay between slides, false for no autoplay (integer or boolean)
            init: 0,        // init delay, false for no delay (integer or boolean)
            pause: !f,      // pause on hover (boolean)
            loop: !f,       // infinitely looping (boolean)
            keys: f,        // keyboard shortcuts (boolean)
            dots: f,        // display dots pagination (boolean)
            arrows: f,      // display prev/next arrows (boolean)
            fluid: f,       // is it a percentage width? (boolean)
            starting: f,    // invoke before animation (function with argument)
            complete: f,    // invoke after animation (function with argument)
            // More key value pairs
        };
```

Now I inspected the plugin a bit and saw the following line :

There's only one line that makes use of this `f` value, see below:

```
if ((!target.length || index < 0) && o.loop == f) return;
```

Now let me elaborate on what my difficulty is:

Obviously in plain JavaScript `f` doesn't mean false, unless you do `f = false`.

I did the below test to confirm that:

```
var obj = {
                    check : !f,
                    myname : "lala"
                } 

                console.log(obj.check);
```

I got an error in the console: "f is not defined".

Well, obviously it's not defined; the console was right. So I went back to the plugin and inspected the plugin. And came across a function that was actually passing the `f` in. Let me describe what I saw, as code will explain more than words:

```
/**
 *   Unslider by @idiot and @damirfoy
 *   Contributors:
 *   - @ShamoX
 *
 */

(function($, f) {

    var Unslider = function() {
        //  Object clone
        var _ = _this = this;

        // a couple of 100 lines of code .    

        //  Set some options
        _this.o = {
            pause: !f,      // pause on hover (boolean)
            loop: !f,       // infinitely looping (boolean)
            keys: f,        // keyboard shortcuts (boolean)
            dots: f,        // display dots pagination (boolean)
            arrows: f,      // display prev/next arrows (boolean)
            prev: '&larr;', // text or html inside prev button (string)
            next: '&rarr;', // same as for prev option
            fluid: f,       // is it a percentage width? (boolean)
            starting: f,    // invoke before animation (function with argument)
            complete: f,    // invoke after animation (function with argument)
        };


            //  To slide or not to slide
            if ((!target.length || index < 0) && o.loop == f) return;


    };

    //  Create a jQuery plugin
    $.fn.unslider = function(o) {
        var len = this.length;

        return this.each(function(index) {

            var me = $(this),   

                instance = (new Unslider).init(me, o);

        });
    };

    Unslider.version = "1.0.0";
})(jQuery, false);
```

Now look right at the top, right at the top of the above code snippet. In this line `(function($, f) {`, that's the line that I found out was the culprit, the `f` it's passing in is actually 'false'; I console.logged and checked that.

So what's my question: well, who on earth is passing that false value and from where and when does that false value get passed? How can I debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the last line of the source, from [the github repo](https://github.com/idiot/unslider/blob/master/src/unslider.js) shows that it is being passed in :

```
})(jQuery, false);
```

look up IIFE http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression to see why it is being passed in

Comment: Holly Molly , yes  i will go ahead an read that , i know about IIFE's but this one really caught me on the wrong foot .

Comment: no problem, there are so many JS patterns it can get quite confusing sometimes